# How can we get gradient with some other loss function apart from MSE?

Tags: gradient-descent, gradient

In most of the gradient search examples, the update to weights are done by subtracting the derivative of `MSE`.

Can we have an example, where we did not use derivative of `MSE`, but used derivative of some other `loss function`?

If so, please show the Python code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we have. MSE loss function is usually used for regression problems. We can have different loss functions according to our needs. Follow the article below.
https://towardsdatascience.com/common-loss-functions-in-machine-learning-46af0ffc4d23

If you wish to learn as to what does gradient does in the algorithm   you can visit this article:
https://towardsdatascience.com/wondering-why-do-you-subtract-gradient-in-a-gradient-descent-algorithm-9b5aabdf8150